# Comparing two groups using factor analysis

Tags: chi-squared-test, factor-analysis

I have a 258*14 dataset, I want to compare the latent factor structure of two sub-groups from this dataset (group1= 146, group2= 112). I started by performing an EFA (using ML and Promax rotation) on the complete dataset, I got a three-factorial solution that is interpretable and has good internal consistency(>0.9). CFA results were as follows: chi2= (185.943, 91, 2.34e-13), CFI and TLI>0.9, RMSEA = 0.084, and all loadings were significant. What can I do regarding the chi2 results? Can I still use this model for multi-group CFA?

I tried also to perform 2 EFA analyses (PAF, Promax) for each group separately, I got a 3-factor solution for both groups but with a different loading pattern (which was expected from the results of the correlation matrices of the two groups). CFA for these models resulted in the same fit indices problem (good TLI, CFI, and RMSEA but very low chi2 p-value). Can I conclude based on the EFA results alone that some items are measuring different constructs between the two groups?

some information on the data:
one group didn't satisfy the multivariate normality assumption (univariate normality is valid in all cases).
kmo and Barlett's test results were as follows:
Group1: kmo: 0.709, Bartlett: (594.226, 5.707e-69)
Group2:kmo: 0.734, Bartlett: (658.204, 8.066e-87)

I am using factor-analysis for EFA and semopy for CFA in python.